# Split ogg-theora video files without re-encoding?

Tags: video, sound, software-recommendation, encoding

Good evening all,

I have decided to rip my entire DVD collection to Ogg-Theora video, specifically a few different TV series' that I have so I don't have to keep digging the discs out.  To do this, I have been using dvd::rip to pull the individual vob files from the disc and then using ffmpeg2theora to encode.  This process has been working great for me until I hit a slight snag.  The dvd I just ripped does not have the individual episodes in vobs, but the entire disc of 7 episodes in one vob.  I went ahead and ripped it and encoded the whole thing into Theora.  Now, how do I split this file into the individual episodes?

I would prefer not to re-encode these, and obviously any prospective program would need a easy way for me to set the 'cut' points.  I have used a few similar programs in Windows (for other formats), but I am unsure of what is out there for Ubuntu.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the answers I have received so far!  I think I have found a utility that works for my needs.  After some research, it seems that Xiph.org (the makers of theora) have a utility that has a chop functionality that takes a time offset (much like the ffmpeg utility that aking1012 [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13455/split-ogg-theora-video-files-without-re-encoding/13459#13459) ) called [oggz-tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/oggz-tools)

```
sudo apt-get install oggz-tools
```

It does a direct stream cut as well, meaning the quality stays the same and the process only takes a about 10-15 seconds.  I have more playing around to do with it, but it seems like a winner after using it for a few videos.

Comment: Good, I am aware of oggz-tools, I use it mainly to embed metadata in theora without re-encoding.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Avidemux available in the repositories, you can install it from the software center, mark the segment you want, select your container type and use the copy options to get the marked segment out without re-encoding, More information about Avidemux here: http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/

Comment: I installed AVIDemux, however, when I try load the file I am working with, it says can not load file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry, it seem after all these years the .ogv format is not supported yet, http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=general:input_formats only the older unofficial .ogm

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Answer (score 1):

this can be easily accomplished with kdenlive if you like gui's or with ffmpeg using
ffmpeg -vcodec copy -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:03:00 -i infile.ogv outfile.ogv
if you want to time slice it...guaranteed no re-encoding of the video with the ffmpeg approach

Comment: note: you should already have all the ffmpeg stuff you need to do this if you have ffmpeg2theora

Comment: I tried out kdenlive, but it was being very unresponsive when trying to view the video in the embedded player.  I also tried out ffmpeg, however, it seems to be re-encoding my video instead of a straight stream copy.  Any ideas?

Comment: vcodec copy shouldn't re-encode it should copy stream data directly....you still get % marks because it has to redo the time markers but....you may need an -acodec same to keep from messing with the audio i'll check